# Fundamental group of the surface of a cube with interior of all edges removed

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Find the fundamental group of the surface of a cube with interior of all edges removed (i.e. the space which consists of the vertices and interior of the faces of the cube.

Can I deformation retract the interior of each face into a cross meeting in the middle of the face made up of two diagonal lines which connects the each vertex to the vertex opposite of it. I can deform this into a sphere which has a lattice on it with 12 different loops. So the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}^{12}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by rewritten is correct, although your intuition is also good.

The specific deformation that you consider will give you the correct fundamental group, but as rewritten says, the loops do not commute so you will get $\mathbb{Z} * \cdots * \mathbb{Z}$ for some number of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. What is that number?

Well, if you think of the resulting object as a sphere less some points, you can see pretty easily that if $X_d = S^2 \setminus \{p_1, \ldots, p_d\}$, then:

- $\pi_1(X_1) = 0$, since this is just a sphere less a single point i.e. a disk.
- $\pi_1(X_2) = \mathbb{Z}$, since this is just a disk less a point (i.e. an annulus).
- $\pi_1(X_3) = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ since this is just an annulus less a point, which deformation retracts onto a wedge of two circles.

If you continue this on, you see that $\pi_1(X_d) = \underbrace{\mathbb{Z} * \cdots * \mathbb{Z}}_{d-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the free product $\mathbb{Z}^{\ast11} = \mathbb{Z}\ast\dots\ast\mathbb{Z}$, as the loops do not commute.

An easier way is that you can "continuously" (not exactly an equivalence but in this case it doesn't matter) deform your set into a cube with $12$ points removed, which is topologically equivalent to a disk with $11$ points removed.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the same theme.

It is correct and very useful that this space deformation retracts onto the criss-crossed subspace. This space is just a connected graph, and the question of determining the fundamental group of a connected graph has a well-known algorithmic answer: you find a maximal tree (in the topological sense?) and then the fundamental group is going to be free with generators corresponding to (almost but not quite literally) to the edges that are not contained in the tree.

Take the tree to be something like this red monstrosity, with the blue lines just providing visual structure so that you see how it fits on the cube. We start from the centre of the topmost face, extend out in all directions, then zig-zag down to the bottom face in the shown way (stuff is happening on the other faces too, we just can't see it) and then we can add one *and only one* edge connecting the centre of the bottommost face to one of the four vertices, so that this tree really does capture all the vertices (if we connected the bottommost central point to the tree with more than one edge, we'd break the tree structure).

Bearing in mind the usual cube edges have been removed, to each of the four horizontal-facing faces in the middle there are two edges which we've missed; there are three edges of the bottom face not found in this tree, and none in the top face. Overall there are $11$ edges of this graph not present in the tree, hence the fundamental group is isomorphic (in a rather explicit way) to the free group on $11$ generators.

[image]